# Problema para obtener los ultimos 5 registros con el método latest() en Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Necesito mostrar mis últimos 5 registros en una tabla, pero me muestra solo los primeros 5. eh investigado y no he tenido solución adjunto mi código del `controller`.

```
function viewaddinsumo() 
{
    //declaramos la variable insumos que esta en addInsumo
    $insumos = \App\insumos::latest()
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
    return view('Insumos/addInsumo',compact('insumos'));
}//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías trabajarlo del modo siguiente

en la parte superior de tu controller invoca el  `namespace`

> Por cierto deberías de seguir la convención de nombres de `Models` en
>   Laravel donde es en *singular* y la primer letra en mayúscula

```
use App\insumos;
```

Posteriormente para realizar tu consulta te debería quedar de este modo

```
$insumos = insumos::orderBy('columnaId', 'DESC')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
```

1.- Aplicando el método `orderBy` le indicamos que haga el ordenamiento de manera `DESC` por medio de la columna `id` *aquí modifica el nombre de la columna por el de tu tabla*

2.- haciendo uso del método `take(5)` y le indico que tome 5 registros que para este caso deberían ser los últimos 5

3.- finalmente para obtener los resultados de la consulta hago uso del método `get()`

**ACTUALIZACIÓN IMPORTANTE PARA EL MÉTODO LATEST()**

> El método tal cual lo tienes funciona el problema es que te esta
>   ordenando pr alguna de las otras columnas de manera descendente,
>   entonces si necesitas que los registros los ordene de manera `DESC` de
>   acuerdo a los registrados necesitas indicarle que trabaje con la
>   columna `id` o como sea que la tienes llamada en tu tabla

Si quieres hacer uso del método `latest()` pero que te devuelva los último registros, necesitas pasarle como parametro la columna `idColumna` por ejemplo
para que haga el ordenamiento *considera que el nombre que uso de `idColumna` es solo un ejemplo ahi debes poner el nombre de la columna que corresponder a tu tabla*

```
$insumos = insumos::latest('idColumna')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Gracias! a funcionado! sin problemas! pero base a eso necesito otra cosa, como puedo realizar que mi tabla se refresque sola?, sin necesidad que refresque toda la pagina?

Comment: eso se consideraría otra pregunta amigo, la cual te invito a publicar por el momento y con lo que entiendo tendrías que usar un llamado por medio de AJAX a una consulta especifica para que pinte de nuevo en el DOM solo la parte de la tabla con los datos que extraiga de dicha consulta

Comment: si gracias por tu ayuda, igual publique una nueva pregunta por algunos problemas, al igual inserte el código gracias por tu ayuda!